# How to find all the critical points of $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2(1-x)^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am Alice :)

So we have critical points when the gradient vector is zero, ie $\left(\frac{\partial \:f}{\partial \:x},\:\frac{\partial \:f}{\partial \:y}\:\right)=\:\left(0,\:0\right)$

So we have:

$f_x = 2x-3y^2\left(1-x\right)^2 = 0$ and $f_y = 2y\left(-x+1\right)^3 = 0$

Okay in $f_y$ we have $x = 1$ and $y = 0$, (this is not a critical point right?). But what about $f_x$? How do you find $x$ and $y$ for $f_x$? Even if you found this what does this x and y mean?

Thanks everyone <3

Comment: So you already *know* that critical points can only occur where $x=1$ or $y=0$. Therefore it suffices to compute $f_x$ at these points only.

Comment: @MartinR Heyy Martin, thanks for commenting. Hmm so lets say we have some other multivariable function, I only need to find$ 0 =$ $f_x$ or $f_y$ only? And I pick the easiest to solve?

Comment: Yes, if you solve a system of multiple equations then you can start by determining the solutions of one equation (the “easiest” one), and substitute the solutions in the other equations. Of course there need not always be one equation which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Critical points are where $f_x(x, y) = 0$ **and** $f_y(x, y) = 0$. You already figured out that $f_y(x, y) = 0$ exactly if $x=1$ or $y= 0$. Therefore it suffices to investigate $f_x$ at those places only:

- If $x=1$ then $f_x(x, y) = 1 \ne 0$.
- If $y=0$ then $f_x(x, y) = x$.

So the only point where both partial derivatives are zero is $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: Heeyy Martin thanks for the quick answers.  Please allow me to extend my question a little bit more. Say if we want to classify this point, do I find the determinant of the Hessian matrix? And classify as according to the condition of $D$, the determinant? Many thanks again

Comment: @AliceRathbone: That is a different question. (But look for example here: https://planetmath.org/relationsbetweenhessianmatrixandlocalextrema .)